# C# - How to use Dictionaries with GUI

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm struggling to understand how a user can add a value to a dictionary with the use of a GUI.

I've managed to do this with the use of a list:

```
    List<Person> clients = new List<Person>();


    Person x = new Person();
    x.Name = nameTextbox.text;
    x.Address = addressTextbox.Text;
    clients.Add(x); 

public void AddClientButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class Person{

    public string Name{
    get {return Name}
    value { name = value;}

    public string Address{
    get {return Address}
    value { name = Address;}
    }

}
```

I've just typed this out as I'm not on my Windows machine (so forgive me so any mistakes),  but none-the-less it works. However, I'm required to use a Dictionary due to the fact it has a Key & Value.

Everyone seems to add the data themselves and within a ConsoleApplication, I'm required to let the User add the data with the use of a GUI. I was wondering if the concept is similar with the use of a Dictionary or are they worlds apart?

```
 Dictionary<string, string> clients = new  Dictionary<string, string();


        Person x = new Person();
        x.Name = nameTextbox.text;
        x.Address = addressTextbox.Text;
        clients.Add(x); 

    public void AddClientButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class Person{

        public string Name{
        get {return Name}
        value { name = value;}

        public string Address{
        get {return Address}
        value { name = Address;}
        }

    }
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction, possibly with the use of an example so I can grasp the concept.

Thank you.

Comment: Word's can't adequately describe how invalid this code is...

Comment: What's the key? And shouldn't your dictionary be a `Dictionary<string, Person>`?

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you are asking, but since `clients` is a dictionary `clients[nameTextbox.text] = addressTextbox.Text` might work

Comment: A few seconds searching for `c# dictionary tutorial` on your favourite search engine will answer all of your questions. First result: https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Comment: Why is the `Class Person` within the `AddClientButton_Click` function?

Comment: Sorry, I typed it out haha, using a Mac do couldn't copy my code across. And I did search, but all using the ConsoleApplication. I  needed to store the value(s) from user input.

Comment: Whether it's console or not is largely irrelevant, the C# code that does the work would be almost identical. It could be as easy as adding some textboxes to your GUI, getting their string values in code and then adding them to the dictionary on a button press.

Comment: @Equalsk I apologise for my stupidity. I never knew this. I'll definitely keep this in mind for future.

Comment: @James Hughes, it wasn't at first. My code was edited my a moderator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming the name of the person is unique**

```
Dictionary<string, Person> clients = new  Dictionary<string, Person>();

 ....

public void AddClientButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        Person x = new Person();
        x.Name = nameTextbox.text;
        x.Address = addressTextbox.Text;
        clients.Add(x.Name, x); //Beware, if the name is not unique an exception will be thrown.

}
```

Comment: Why not just `Dictionary<string, string>` with the key as the name and value as the address?

Comment: Thank you so much, may I ask as to why clients.Add(x.Name, x); has another X at the end?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I don't know whether the Person class has more properties.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder how would you go about this?

Comment: @user6353178 because you're saving in the dictionary the Person, which it is the value.

Comment: @raven I agree but for the example I was just stating that, that is also possible

Comment: @Raven, class only has 3 properties two string and a bool.

Comment: @user6353178  Ok, so if you need to store the whole Person object. You may want to store it in the dictionary as in my answer. Otherwise, you won't be able to see the value of the bool property, when you query the dictionary.

Comment: @raven thank you so much buddy. I appreciate it. Just a quick question, would everything else be similar to as if I was using a List<Person> ? i.e. the remove method etc?

Comment: To Remove, you would need to call `clients.Remove("PersonName")` and again, if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary an exception will be thrown too. You may want refer to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to see all dictionary methods.